# Selenium Webdriver Locators

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am automating a report submission process in `WebDriver`, the report has multiple pages and in all the page there will be `Next` button to proceed to next page.

The next button has a following locators,

```
<a class="buttonNext btn btn-green btnwidth" href="javascript:;" style="">Next</a>
```

The problem is all the `Next` buttons in the report has the same locators since the wizard contains the next, previous and submit button is common throughout the report and only the page content will change, but this panel remains the same throughout the report.

I can use the `xpath` of the `Next` button which is :

```
.//*[@id='wizard']/div[2]/a[3]
```

This `xpath` is same for all the places where the `Next` button is placed in the report.

My coding is given as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wizard']/div[2]/a[3]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,2500)");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wizard']/div[2]/a[3]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wizard']/div[2]/a[3]")).click();

//WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
//WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Next")));

 driver.findElement(By.id("SignatureDate")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("SignatureDate")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("SignatureDate")).sendKeys("01/09/2016");
```

`WebDriver` is idenfying the first `Next` button `xpath` and clicking it, but for next two pages again I'm providing the same `xpath` to access the `Next` button, but the selenium throws me the error message as :-

> ElementNotVisibleexception:element not visible.

How can I differentiate the `Next` button to identify it for `WebDriver`?

**Note** : The report is opened in `iframe` & I'm working in `iframe`.

Comment: Why are you commented this line of code `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Next")));`?? why are you not trying with this code to wait until element visible and clickable every time??

Comment: I have tried that code as executable as well, but it is not working for me.

Comment: What do you mean not working?? what was the exception when you tried with `WebDriverWait`??

Comment: You should try every time as `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.buttonNext"))).click()`..:)

Comment: As per your advice i have added the code as below, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wizard']/div[2]/a[3]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,2500)");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.buttonNext"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.buttonNext"))).click();  But it still throws me a error like ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Answer (score 1):

You can use Explicit Wait to allow the page to load completely before it tries to click the Next Button on the other page.
Also, if using iFrames you can use the below:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("FRAME_NAME"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `By.cssSele‌​ctor()` every time with using `WebDriverWait` after switching back from `iframe` to `defaulContent()` as below :-

```
//Do your stuff inside iframe

//Now switch back to default content
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSele‌​ctor("a.buttonNext")‌​)).click()
```